# updating an excel spreadsheet with lookup function

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

Ive watched an hour on lookup functions and dug through forums but cannot figure out how to update an existing database with new info from an online source (rather than using cntrl f, then cntrl c/v hundreds of times every few days). My strategy is to have the old database table next to the new database table (the old table includes all new table info except whether or not a row has been tempered with). I want the old table to update with a column that conditionally formats with a yes if the new table from online shows particular rows have been tampered with. I'm assuming in need to incorporate the search function with lookup but i'm admittedly and absolute noob.

Thanks for any possible advice, I'm sure this is an easy fix so I apologize in advance if my ignorance offends you...

Comment: Why keep the old data?  Can you treat the excel data as old and create a routine to 'refresh' it when a task needs to be completed.  That way you always have the accurate master data and you aren't left with trying to maintain two copies.

Comment: Only a small percentage, ~10%, is being updated each few days (with some overlap each time). I wish there was just a refresh routine but I think this assumes that I have the same amount of data each time, when really it's a only one column that needs to be refreshed and done so only if it is matched to the new set of data.

Comment: Regardless thanks for your time. Good day

Answer (score 0):

This may need edits, because I'm not clear what you are looking for.

I would create a KEY column in the "new" table (Sheet1?), that concatenates all of the fields together, separated by a period.  If there were only four columns, the fifth column would have:

```
=A1&"."&B1&"."&C1&"."&D1
```

Then in the old database (on Sheet2?), I would create the following column that looks to see if the existing row matches anything in the "new" table (Sheet1):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1&"."&B1&"."&C1&"."&D1,Sheet1!$D:$D))
```

Entries labelled "FALSE" don't match up with anything in the "new" table.

Comment: Hey thanks for the example code, it's not working completely yet but it's certainly better than where I was starting with using Lookup functions. Good day